# Вызов шаблонной функции через Qtconcurrent::run

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонная функция:

```
template <typename Function , typename ...Args>
auto exceptionWrapper (Object *obj, Function&& function, Args&& ...args)-> decltype((obj->*function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    try
    {
        QScopedPointer<Object> tempObj(new Object(obj->getSomeData()));
        return (tempObj->*function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Есть другая функция, которая ее вызывает через `qtConcurrent::run`:

```
template <typename Function , typename ...Args, typename CallBack>
void Object::callAsync(Object *obj,Function&& query,CallBack&& callBack, Args&& ...args)
{

    using ReturnValue = decltype(exceptionWrapper(obj, query, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    QFutureWatcher<ReturnValue> watcher;
    connect(&watcher, &QFutureWatcher <ReturnValue>::finished, callBack);
    QFuture<ReturnValue> futureValue = QtConcurrent::run(exceptionWrapper, obj, query, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    watcher.setFuture(futureValue);
}
```

При попытке вызова в коде:

```
 Object object = new Object();
 Object::callAsync(object, Object::objFcn, [](){qDebug()<<"qq";}, arg1, arg2);
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
ошибка: no matching function for call to 'run(<unresolved overloaded function type>, BOKZDatabase*&, AngleOrientData (BOKZDatabase::*&)(const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, int), const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const int&)'
     QFuture<ReturnValue> futureValue = QtConcurrent::run(exceptionWrapper, db, query, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                                                     ^
```

Что я упустил?

UPD:
В случае явного указания параметров шаблона ошибка о неопределенном типе функции остается:

```
template <typename Function , typename ...Args, typename CallBack>
void Object::callAsync (Object *obj,Function&& query,CallBack&& callBack, Args&& ...args)
{

    using ReturnValue = decltype(exceptionWrapper(obj, query, args...));
    QFutureWatcher<ReturnValue> watcher;
    connect(&watcher, &QFutureWatcher <ReturnValue>::finished, callBack);
    QFuture<ReturnValue> futureValue = QtConcurrent::run(exceptionWrapper <Function, Args...>, obj, std::forward<Function>(query), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    watcher.setFuture(futureValue);
}
```

UPD 2. Минимальный пример:

```
class Object
{
public:
    int sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
};


template <typename Function , typename ...Args>
auto fcn (Object *object, Function&& function, Args&& ...args)-> decltype ((object->*function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
   return (object->*function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename Function , typename ...Args>
void callAsync(Object *object,Function&& function, Args&& ...args)
{

    QtConcurrent::run(fcn <Function, std::forward<Args...>>, object, function, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Object* obj = new Object();

    callAsync(obj, Object::sum, 5, 6);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exceptionWrapper` сам по себе не является функцией, но неким шаблоном функции, поэтому мы не можем никуда его передать — мы можем передавать лишь что-то конкретное, а не абстракцию, коей является шаблон.

Таким образом, нам нужно конкретизировать (инстанциировать) `exceptionWrapper` прежде чем передавать его в `QtConcurrent::run`. Здесь встаёт другая проблема: с какими аргументами инстанциировать? Т.к. `exceptionWrapper` использует пробрасывающую ссылку (forwarding reference), идёт расчёт на то, что аргументы будут выводиться при вызове функции, но у нас ситуация иная — мы явно задаём аргументы шаблона. Конечно, мы всё равно получаем нужный результат таким вызовом:

```
QtConcurrent::run(exceptionWrapper<Function, Args...>, obj, std::forward<Function>(query), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Происходит это из-за того, что у нас в `callAsync` пробрасывающая ссылка, а в `exceptionWrapper`, в результате явной инстанциации, у нас rvalue-ссылка, и  применяя правила C++ по свертке ссылок мы на выходе имеем то, что и ожидали: будет инстанциирована правильная, т.е. ожидаемая нами функция `exceptionWrapper`. К примеру, если мы рассмотрим минимальный пример, из Вашего дополненного вопроса, то при таком вызове:

```
int var = 5;
callAsync(obj, &Object::sum, 7, var);
```

Будет сгенерирована функция `exceptionWrapper` с такой сигнатурой: `int (Object *,int (Object::* )(int,int),int &&,int &)` — как раз то, что и ожидалось. Но в этом кроется другая проблема. Мы работаем с конкурентной средой и пытаемся вызвать метод Qt, который потенциально выполнит наш метод в другом потоке. Но, чтобы выполнить метод в другом потоке, он вынужден скопировать (либо же переместить, если умеет) аргументы и сохранить их до того времени, когда можно будет вызвать нашу функцию.

Сохраняя наши аргументы, Qt отбрасывает их изначальный тип и впоследствии, при передаче их в нашу функцию, все наши аргументы станут lvalue. Но в сигнатуре нашей функции есть `int&&`, который является rvalue-ссылкой и lvalue не может быть передано туда! Поэтому, нам придётся отказаться от пробрасывающих ссылок в `exceptionWrapper` — они там не нужны и только мешают, там нужен обычный `const &`.

В результате получим такое решение:

```
template <typename Function , typename ...Args>
auto fcn(Object *object, Function function, const Args& ...args)
{
   return (object->*function)(args...);
}

template <typename Function , typename ...Args>
void callAsync(Object *object, Function&& function, Args&& ...args)
{
    QtConcurrent::run(fcn<Function, Args...>, object, function,
                      std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Конечно, можно подумать и над альтернативными решениями, но этот ответ уже и так довольно длинный получился.

Comment: можно поподробнее? вы имеете в виду указать так: QtConcurrent::run(exceptionWrapper <Function, Args...>, obj, query, std::forward<Args>(args)...) ?

Comment: @bronstein87, да

Comment: я обновил пост, посмотрите пожалуйста. при явном указании типа функции ошибка всё равно остается...

Comment: @bronstein87, можете привести минимальный пример, где ошибка воспроизводится и который можно легко собрать и проверить? Без этого сложно Вам помочь.

Comment: добавил минимальный пример

Comment: @bronstein87, обновил ответ.